# Exclude some columns from adding a suffix in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add some suffix (.1) to all columns in one dataset, except the ones that I will later use for matching, whose names I do not want to change. 
I'm trying this but it is giving me an error ("lengths do not match..."):

```
colnames(df[,-which(names(df)==c("survey", "ID", "HID"))]) <- paste(colnames(df[,-which(names(df)==c("survey", "ID", "HID"))]), "1", sep = ".")
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a frequent mistake.
First you extract a sub-dataframe from `df`. Then get its `colnames`. Then change those names. You did not change the column names of the *original* dataframe, only of the sub-df. And this sub-df is lost when the instruction ends.

```
icol <- which(names(df) %in% c("survey", "ID", "HID"))
colnames(df)[-icol] <- paste(colnames(df)[-icol], "1", sep = ".")
```

Comment: Thanks! Both the extracting and the use of  `==` instead of `%in%` were causing the problem.